# My page does not stay the same page when I click the option submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm a little new here. I tried to make my website on my own and although it is almost finished, I can not solve the problem of sending information in my contact form.

The page is this: ramproducciones.pe (it's in Spanish)
If they go towards the end they find the contact form, even if they fill the data correctly, the email is sent but the next thing is that a blank page is given. What I want is that you get a message that says Thank you! Your message has been sent but I do not know how to do it. I have tried to copy many codes and I currently have this:

```
<!-- contacto-->

   <section class="contact" id="contact">

       <h1>Contacto</h1>
        <hr/>       

        <div class="content">

          <div class="form">

            <form method="post" action="mail.php" name="contact">

            <div class="column">NOMBRE<br/><br/>
            <input name="name" id="name" value="" />
            </div>

            <div class="column-2">E-MAIL<br/><br/>
            <input name="email" id="email" value="" />
            </div>


            <div class="column-3">MENSAJE<br/><br/>        
            <textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea>
            </div> 

              <div class="button">
                <span><input class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="ENVIAR"></span>
              </div>

              <div id="dialog-message" title="Thank You">
              <p>¡Gracias! Tu mensaje ha sido enviado, te responderemos lo antes posible.</p>
              </div>

            </form>

          </div>


          <div class="contact-text">

          No dudes en solicitarnos información.<br/><br/>


          <strong>RAM Producciones</strong><br/><br/>

          e-mail: <strong>info@ramproducciones.com</strong>

          <br/><br/>

            <a href="https://facebook.com/RAMproduccionesSAC" target="_blank"><img src=img/social/Facebook.png /></a> 
            <a href="https://vimeo.com/ramproduccionessac" target="_blank"><img src=img/social/Vimeo.png /></a> 
            <a href="https://www.behance.net/RAMProduccionesSAC" target="_blank"><img src=img/social/Behance.png /></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ram.producciones" target="_blank"><img src=img/social/Instagram.png /></a> 
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIF9shcqE4D5cF5Xp7LBasg" target="_blank"><img src=img/social/Youtube.png /></a>

          </div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

AND THE PHP is

```
<?php 

// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = "";
$name = $email = $message = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Solo ingresa letras y espacios."; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Tu E-mail es necesario";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Formato de E-mail inválido"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }

      $to = 'info@ramproducciones.pe';
      $subject = 'Mail vía RAMPRODUCCIONES.PE';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message)){
          $success = "¡Gracias! Tu mensaje ha sido enviado, te responderemos lo antes posible.";
          $name = $email = $message = '';
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

However I still can not solve the problem.

Comment: It's your action.

Comment: its goes mail.php file.

Comment: When the form is submitted, you send them away to another page, with this `action="mail.php"` in your form-tag. Also, its worth noting that `test_input()` functions are mostly useless and just mangles the data instead of providing "security".

Comment: So your mail page does not return content....

Comment: btw, you never echo'd `$success`. Do that and change the action of your page to be self with the entire code in the same file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new in this, so I'm trying to learn. So, I understand that I have to change the action, but what I put instead of mail.php? and I don't understand where I have to put the echo $sucess. I tried with 'PHP_SELF' but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It's your action. You're sending your page to another page called mail.php.  Set the action to reload your current page when the form is submitted.

Try using

`<form id='form' method='post' action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>'>`

as an attribute in your form

In the top of your page where you run your code for successful form submission, hide the form then display your message.

```
  echo "<style>#form{display:none}</style>";
  echo "<p>Thank you for submitting</p>";
```

Comment: `PHP_SELF` is very unsecure, you shall first remove html with `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possibilities in your case. Clearshot66 has introduced one.

Another possibility would be to keep your mail.php page and after the sending of the e-mail, you could create a logic to send the user back to your main page and show him a message. This could be done as I show you below:

mail.php

```
header("Location: your_main_page.php?showMessage=1");
exit;
```

your_main_page.php

```
<?php
    if ($_GET["showMessage"] == 1) {
        echo "Thanks for your contact.";
    }
?>
```

The above code should be put in the beggining of your main_page.php

This is another IDEA.

The best good practice is to send the form using some ajax request and handle the return of this request, but this is a little bit more sofisticated than the options that we pointed to you.

Answer (score 0):

As @clearshot66 said, you are redirecting to mail.php. I understand, that the php page you mean is this file.

What Fredi -ii- saw, you forgot to echo `$success`.

Blank page happens, because there is no output.

Hope I helped.